# Does anyone know the reference for this hadith

Tags: hadith

I've heard this hadith being quoted as evidence for the Sufi hadra but cant find the reference even though its said to be in sahih Muslim "An army came from Ethiopia beating drums on the day of the feast in the mosque. The Prophet (صلى الله عليه وسلم) invited me and I put my palms on his shoulders and watched them play". Can anyone find the reference for this please.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds similar to the hadith of the Ethiopians playing with their spears and shields on the day of Eid.

> عن عائشة، قالت جاء حبش يزفنون في يوم عيد في المسجد فدعاني النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فوضعت رأسي على منكبه فجعلت أنظر إلى لعبهم حتى كنت أنا التي أنصرف عن النظر إليهم
>
> It was narrated that 'Aishah said: "Some Ethiopians came to give a display (with their weapons) in the Masjid on the day of 'Id. The Prophet ﷺ called me and I put my head on his shoulder and started watching their display, until I was the one who decided to stop watching them."
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:892f)</sup>

There are ahadith about this in [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:949) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:893) and various other collections as well.